# yaml2json is parsing just a single line-- exits without error --windows

Tags: npm, yaml, npm-install

I am using yaml2json for the first time. My OS is Windows 7 and I am using git bash. 
May be I am missing something very basic, can you guys please help/guide me here.

I tried sending the output of the bash text processing command to test.yml and I can see the test.yml file is created properly. But once I feed it as a input to yaml2json, it parses just the first line "version" :1 and exits without any error.

However, If I try to convert test.yml file contents online via site:--http://yamltojson.com/-- the resulting .json is proper.

Following are the contents of test.yml file generated:--

```
version: 1
layout: post
lang: en
slug: "checklist"
type: "modal"
title: "Checklist"
published: "true"
categories: "mobile"
tags: "mobile"
action:

title: "Disguise Now" link: "close"
title: "Cancel" link: "home-ready" status: disabled checklist:
title: "Review security plan and update contacts regularly"
```

[image: yaml2json output]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by starting the document with

```
---
```

So for example ...

```
---
    version: 1
    layout: post
    lang: en
    slug: "checklist"
    type: "modal"
    title: "Checklist"
    published: "true"
    categories: "mobile"
    tags: "mobile"
```

... works well, but may not solve your problem because you are using a generated yaml file.

There are more problems with yaml2json (e.g. interpreting the sign of a negative number as list item indicator). So in many cases I use a simple python script (python 2.7 or higher provided) instead of using yaml2json. Only disadvantage I can see is that as opposed to yaml2json the order of dictionary entries is not preserved, but that's just a cosmetical issue, not a logical one:

```
python -c 'import sys, json, yaml; print json.dumps(yaml.load(sys.stdin), indent=4)' < myyamlfile.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

@yaccob's solution worked for me. Just had to add the Loader `yaml.load(sys.stdin, Loader=yaml.FullLoader` parameter to avoid the deprecation warning:

```
python2 -c 'import sys, json, yaml; print json.dumps(yaml.load(sys.stdin, Loader=yaml.FullLoader), indent=4)' < sample.yaml
```